# Types of oops concepts

Tags: c#

What are the oops concepts avaliable in C#?

Comment: You mean "oops" as in mistake? I think the `lock` keyword and covariant array types are often considered to be "oops"es.

Comment: duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402984/main-concepts-in-oop

Comment: inheritance,polymorphism..all concepts are available
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep
here you will find your rtequired stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy, all the OOPs consepts are available in c# but with an advanced version...
    * Inheritance
    * Encapsulation
    * Abstraction
    * Polymorphism

Answer (score 0):

Everything that you would need, in C# way of course.